# July 2013 AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManagerCombiner Errors

Tags: ajax, runtime-error, ajaxcontroltoolkit, nullreferenceexception, invalidoperationexception

Hello we are recieving a few different errors on our surver after we upgraded to the July 2013 version of AjaxControlToolKit.  It appears if the users go back to the previous screen and attempt to execute the same process they previousily did, they will not get an error.

Our AjaxControlToolkit.config file is as follows:

```
<ajaxControlToolkit>
  <controlBundles>
    <controlBundle>
      <control name="TabContainer" />
      <control name="ModalPopupExtender" />
    </controlBundle>
  </controlBundles>
</ajaxControlToolkit>
```

We are getting the following errors:

- System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

  - at AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManagerCombiner.GetScriptReferences(HttpContextBase context, String[] bundles) in f:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\80acd78aa4c25314\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ToolkitScriptManager\ToolkitScriptManagerCombiner.cs:line 211
- System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

  - at AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManagerCombiner.<>c_*DisplayClass9.b*_7(ScriptReference s) in f:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\80acd78aa4c25314\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ToolkitScriptManager\ToolkitScriptManagerCombiner.cs:line 211
- System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.

  - at AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManagerCombiner.GetCombinedScriptContent(HttpContextBase context, String[] bundles, String hash) in f:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\80acd78aa4c25314\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ToolkitScriptManager\ToolkitScriptManagerCombiner.cs:line 140
- System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.

  - at AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManagerHelper.GetAssembly(String name) in f:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\80acd78aa4c25314\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ToolkitScriptManager\ToolkitScriptManagerHelper.cs:line 19

If anyone has any assistance on how to solve any of these errors or have seen them before that would be great.

Thanks!

Austin